# NSTextView doesn’t work when placed near the top of an NSWindow

Tags: macos, notifications, nswindow, nstextview, nsalert

**Context**

I have a window with a `fullSizeContentView` and a transparent titlebar and hidden titlebar.
I don’t even want the titlebar, but I had to enable it to get rounded corners on the `NSWindow`.

**Problem**

An `NSTextView`, when placed near the top edge, doesn’t react to *any* clicks. It doesn‘t let me select any text, and doesn’t let me click links I added via NSAttributedString.

This issue disappears when I disable the titlebar altogether.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Big Context**

I’m trying to implement little “in-app notifications” that show peripheral status updates. I considered using NSAlert but I don’t want to prevent the user from interacting with the rest of the interface while the notifications are showing, so I decided to implement it myself.

The notifications are little, non-movable windows without a titlebar. They are basically just grey rectangles with rounded corners and a shadow that draw inside the main application window and contain one or a few lines of text. The first line of text is almost entirely behind the invisible titlebar which is why I’m having issues.

The only thing I need the notifications to do besides display text is link to webpages that contain more info about a notification’s message.

I feel like I might be approaching this wrong. If you have any suggestions or ideas on how to solve the problem, I’m eager to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

I nailed it down to the `contentInsets` of the `NSScrollView`. (which your are for some reason forced to have around your `NSTextView` when creating it in Interface Builder) 
The `contentInsets` were automatically being set to account for the invisible titlebar, even though the docs say that `NSScrollView - automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets` (which is set to YES by default and which I assume was causing this) doesn't do automatic insets for transparent titlebars.

After programmatically setting the scrollView's `contentInsets` to 0, everything works great!
In Objective C, you can set your scrollView's `contentInsets` to 0 like this:

```objectivec
NSScrollView *scrollView = (NSScrollView *)self.textView.superview.superview;
scrollView.automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets = NO; // Doesn't remove insets // Probably calling this too late
scrollView.contentInsets = NSEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

[Here](https://mega.nz/file/bpJiERaB#7fGZviTN7accFrFYdQ3Gonq2cY07zBAdnxQg3k2ELTw)'s a working example.

Hope this helps!